# Highlight text with javascript when embedded video reaches certain position

Tags: javascript

I have a page with a long embedded video and section titles with buttons that enable users to jump to a specific time in the video. I would like to be able to highlight the next title when the video time reaches the relevant timestamp.

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <table class="toc" width="400">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1.1 Course Introduction</td>
                    <td><button class="playbutton" onclick="Section11()" type="button">
                        </button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1.2 Introduction to the Software</td>
                    <td><button class="playbutton" onclick="Section12()" type="button">
                        </button></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <video id="myvideo" width="1160" height="100%" controls>
            <source src="SW101.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    var vid = document.getElementById("myvideo");
    function Section11() {
        vid.currentTime = 0;
        vid.play();
    }
    function Section12() {
        vid.currentTime = 312;
        vid.play();
    } 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a working version of what you want, you basically listen to the on-time update event on the video, and add a class if the current time exceeds a certain threshold that you defined in the chapters object.

```js
var vid = document.getElementById("myvideo");
const wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper')
const chapters = {
  0: wrapper.querySelector('[data-chapter="1"]'),
  5: wrapper.querySelector('[data-chapter="2"]')
}

vid.addEventListener('timeupdate', (event) => {
  let currentChapter = null
  for (let chapter in chapters) {
    if (chapter < vid.currentTime) {
      //search for the latest chapter to the current time
      currentChapter = chapter
    }

  }
  wrapper.querySelectorAll('.highlighted').forEach(ele => {
    ele.classList.remove('highlighted')
  })
  chapters[currentChapter].classList.add('highlighted')
})
```

```css
.highlighted {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <table class="toc" width="400">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td data-chapter="1">1.1 Course Introduction</td>
          <td><button class="playbutton" onclick="Section11()" type="button"> 
</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td data-chapter="2">1.2 Introduction to SuccessFactors</td>
          <td><button class="playbutton" onclick="Section12()" type="button"> 
</button></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <video id="myvideo" width="1160" height="100%" controls>
<source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ontimeupdate` event to check your video time is reached to a specific point or not. this is an example from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_av_event_timeupdate)

```js
// Get the <video> element with id="myVideo"
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");

// Assign an ontimeupdate event to the <video> element, and execute a function if the current playback position has changed
vid.ontimeupdate = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
// Display the current position of the video in a <p> element with id="demo"
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = vid.currentTime;
}
```